# Marshalling C# from DLL to WPF form

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, marshalling

It is possible to "Marshalling" from DLL to WPF Form? For example I like to update Listbox. Which will be the better way to do it?

Before (when I have everthing in one app) I have so defined:

```
MyMarshalDataToForm(FormActions.AddItemToListBox, "Handle obtained to my device:");
```

Where,

```
private enum FormActions
{
    AddItemToListBox,
    DisableInputReportBufferSize,
    EnableGetInputReportInterruptTransfer,
    EnableInputReportBufferSize,
    EnableSendOutputReportInterrupt,
    ScrollToBottomOfListBox,
    SetInputReportBufferSize
}
```

Where,

```
private void MyMarshalDataToForm(FormActions action, String textToDisplay)
{
    try
    {
        object[] args = { action, textToDisplay };

        //  The AccessForm routine contains the code that accesses the form.

        MarshalDataToForm marshalDataToFormDelegate = AccessForm;

        //  Execute AccessForm, passing the parameters in args.

        Dispatcher.Invoke(marshalDataToFormDelegate, args);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayException(Name, ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Sorry for so few information in my first post. Now I want to leave Mashal data in .dll and update (for example) ListBox in Main Form. How to do it?

Comment: Can you add a reference to that dll and use its classes or you are constrained to use reflection?

Comment: What language is the .dll you are marshalling from written in? Am I correct in guessing C++?

Comment: Sorry. dll will be written in C# (by me) and is not finished yet. Before I have everything in one app - so I update "Listbox" easy direct to WPF Form. Now I want to divide "FORM" part and .dll part.

Comment: Sorry and Thanks - Poke, Hidden Hobbes and Shadwell :) Now I understand

Comment: As already pointed out: make a reference to that DLL and use its classes. Best regards,

Comment: But how? :) Any already do that? Any example?  Which reference to take in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Lacking [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your scenario, it's not possible to know what the best approach would be.

However, a common approach for separating concerns between main program and DLL like this would be for the DLL to declare an `event` that the main program can subscribe to.

For example, in the DLL:

```
public delegate void FormActionHandler(FormActions action, string textToDisplay);

public event FormActionHandler FormAction;

private void MyMarshalDataToForm(FormActions action, String textToDisplay)
{
    try
    {
        object[] args = { action, textToDisplay };

        //  The AccessForm routine contains the code that accesses the form.

        MarshalDataToForm marshalDataToFormDelegate = FormAction;

        //  Execute AccessForm, passing the parameters in args.

        if (marshalDataToFormDelegate != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(marshalDataToFormDelegate, args);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayException(Name, ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Then in your main program where, presumable, the `AccessForm()` method is declared, you would have some code like this:

```
myDllObject.FormAction += AccessForm;
```

In this way, when the DLL needs to call the `AccessForm()` method, it need not actually know about the method per se. Instead, it uses the delegate already created by the main program to call that method, which has been subscribed to the `FormAction` event.

Note that the above uses a non-standard event signature. This is perfectly legal, but if you want to follow the .NET standard `EventHandler<T>`-based convention, you can do that too. It involves more code, but has the advantage of being a more-readily-recognizable event pattern.

For example:

```
class FormActionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public FormActions Action { get; private set; }
    public string TextToDisplay { get; private set; }

    public FormActionEventArgs(FormActions action, string textToDisplay)
    {
        Action = action;
        TextToDisplay = textToDisplay;
    }
}

public event EventHandler<FormActionEventArgs> FormAction;

private void MyMarshalDataToForm(FormActions action, String textToDisplay)
{
    try
    {
        FormActionEventArgs args = new FormActionEventArgs(action, textToDisplay);

        //  The AccessForm routine contains the code that accesses the form.

        EventHandler<FormActionEventArgs> marshalDataToFormDelegate = FormAction;

        //  Execute AccessForm, passing the parameters in args.

        if (marshalDataToFormDelegate != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(marshalDataToFormDelegate, this, args);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayException(Name, ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Then your main program would subscribe like this:

```
myDllObject.FormAction += (sender, e) =>
{
    AccessForm(e.Action, e.TextToDisplay);
};
```